# Computing median of std::vector<double> causing segfault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stdvector, median

The following function is supposed to compute the median of a `std::vector<double>`.

```
double vecMed(vector<double>& vec) {

    vector<double> copyVec = vec;

    sort(copyVec.begin(), copyVec.end());

    if( copyVec.size()%2 == 0)
        return (copyVec[floor(static_cast<double>(copyVec.size())/2.0)] + copyVec[ceil(static_cast<double>(copyVec.size())/2.0)]) / 2.0;
    else
        return copyVec[copyVec.size()/2];
}
```

I'm getting a segfault on this line, sometimes:

```
return (copyVec[floor(static_cast<double>(copyVec.size())/2.0)] + copyVec[ceil(static_cast<double>(copyVec.size())/2.0)]) / 2.0;
```

Can anyone see a problem with this function?

The segfault might be due to memory corruption elsewhere that I'm unaware of, but I want to make sure I'm not making a subtle or careless mistake in the above code before I explore that possibility.

---

GDB says:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000428ab6 in vecMed (this=0x7fffffffd1b0, vec=...) at ../globals.cpp:834
834         return (copyVec[floor(static_cast<double>(copyVec.size())/2.0)] + copyVec[ceil(static_cast<double>(copyVec.size())/2.0)]) / 2.0;
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000428ab6 in vecMed (this=0x7fffffffd1b0, vec=...) at ../globals.cpp:834
```

Comment: Just print out the indices you are using to access the vector's elements.

Comment: Do you get the error when `copyVec.size()==0`?

Comment: I'd simplify the two indices to `size()/2` and `size()/2 + 1`. I don't think the squiggly floating-point arithmetic is the problem here, but there's plenty of room for unexpected rounding errors to push the indices out of range.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but you don't need the casts; `copyVec.size()/2.0` has type `double`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So much errors in the code!
I guess you want:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

double vecMed(std::vector<double> vec) {
    if(vec.empty()) return 0;
    else {
        std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
        if(vec.size() % 2 == 0)
                return (vec[vec.size()/2 - 1] + vec[vec.size()/2]) / 2;
        else
                return vec[vec.size()/2];
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to sort the vector to get the median. That is not efficient.

Answer (score 4):

First off, if the initial vector is empty, what you're doing is not safe.

Secondly, your logic isn't right in the even case. If `copyVec.size() % 2 == 0`, it's even, so `static_cast<double>(copyVec.size())/2.0` is an integer. So both the floor and ceil are the same thing, so that's probably not what you want to do. Prefer something like:

```
const int mid = copyVec.size() / 2;
if (copyVec.size() % 2 == 0) {
    return 0.5 * (copyVec[mid] + copyVec[mid+1]); // safe unless size == 0
}
else {
    return copyVec[mid]; // e.g. if size == 3, return copyVec[1]
}
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes it should :) fixed

Comment: Wow, now I really feel like an idiot.  But that's OK, because nothing like a kick of humility to wake one up in the morning :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return 0.5 * (copyVec[mid-1] + copyVec[mid]);` when size is even?  If size == 4, then mid equals 2.  Then I want average of `copyVec[1]` and `copyVec[2]`, not `copyVec[2]` and `copyVec[3]`.  Right?

Comment: I would still go with an nth_element version. Code will be shorter and will perform better.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need floor of ceil, you can do this far more efficiently using integer arithmetic:

```
return (copyVec[copyVec.size()/2] + copyVec[(copyVec.size() + 1)/2]) / 2.0;
```

Now this code will do the same as yours but it is easier to read and understand.
Start by trying out some simple cases and some edge cases. In this case you may note that your code does not run correctly for an empty array.

Lets assume you don't see anything suspicious in the code you investigate your best option is to use a debugger. Sometimes using valgrind would also help if you have a stack corruption.

Also you may want to consider using `std::nth_element` for finding the median of a vector.